# Does Shankara teach to renounce one's own duties?

Tags: advaita, adi-shankaracharya, padma-purana

Padma Purana 6.236:

> The doctrine of illusion (Mayavada) is an impious, wicked belief and
>   against all the conclusions of the Vedas. It is only covered Buddhism.
>   My dear Parvati, in Kali-Yuga I assume the form of a brahmana (Adi
>   Shankara) and teach this imagined philosophy.(7)
>
> The doctrine of Mayavada shows the meaninglessness of the words of the
>   holy texts and is condemned in the world. **In this (doctrine) only the
>   giving up of one's own duties is expounded**.(8)

Padma Purana says in the doctrine of Mayavada, giving up of one's own duties is expounded. However, is this what Shankara taught?

Answer (score 8):

Shankara said Svadharma is necessary for purity of mind:

> One who is passionately devoted to the authority of the Śrutis
>   acquires steadiness in **his Svadharma, which alone conduces to the
>   purity of his mind. The man of pure mind realises the Supreme Self**,
>   and by this alone Samsara with its root is destroyed. (Vivekachudamani
>   148)

And according to Shankara, an unenlightened person shouldn't give up his Svadharma.

An excerpt from Shankara's commentary on Bhagavad Gita 18.48:

> Kaunteya, O son of Kunti; na tyajet, **one should not give up;-what?-the
>   karma, duty; sahajam, to which one is born, which devolves from the
>   very birth**; api, even though; it be sadosam, faulty, consisting as it
>   is of the three gunas. Hi, for; sarva-arambhah, all undertakings
>   (-whatever are begun are arambhah, i.e. ‘all actions’, according to
>   the context-), being constituted by the three gunas (-here, the fact
>   of being constituted by the three gunas is the cause-); are avrtah,
>   surrounded; dosena, with evil; iva, as;; agnih, fire; is dhumena, with
>   smoke, which comes into being concurrently. One does not get freed
>   from evil by giving up the duty to which one is born-called one’s own
>   duty-, even though (he may be) fulfilling somebody else’s duty.
>   Another’s duty, too, is fraught with fear. The meaning is: **Since action cannot be totally given up by an unenlightened person, therefore he should not relinquish it**.